# Errors in PHP calculating date, hours and minutes?

Tags: php, html

My problem is that I get the issue

> Notice: Trying to get property '7444' of non-object in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\ex2.php on line 22

days have passed.
So it calculates the time, day and etc but it doesn't want to show on my page.

```
          <html>
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="8ex2.css">
          <body>
          <div class="inside">
          Welcome <?php echo $_POST["name"]; ?><br>

          Your Birthday is: <?php echo $_POST["dob"]; ?><br>

          <?php
              $date = $_POST["dob"];
              $now = time();
              $birthDay = strtotime($date);

              $newBDate = date("d-M-Y", strtotime($date));

              $todaysDate=getdate();
              $difference = $now - $birthDay;
              $minutes = floor($difference/ (60));
              $hours = floor($difference/ (60*60));
              $days = floor($difference / (60*60*24));
              $weeks = floor($difference / (60*60*24*7));

              echo $difference->$days.' days have passed.<br>';
              echo $difference->$hours.' hours have passed.<br>';
              echo $difference->$minutes.' minutes have passed.<br>';

                ?>
          </div>
          </body>
          </html>
```

Which I don't understand is there something that I am doing incorrectly in my PHP?

Answer (score 2):

Why the `$difference->$days`? The variable is called `$days`.

Just do

```
echo $days.' days have passed.<br>';
echo $hours.' hours have passed.<br>';
echo $minutes.' minutes have passed.<br>';
```

Comment: Yeah my bad stupid mistake thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the native [DateInterval](http://php.net/manual/fr/dateinterval.format.php) from the [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/fr/class.datetime.php) class here

```
// Create the initial date object
$datetime1 = new DateTime($_POST["dob"]);

// Compare it to now
$interval = $datetime1->diff(new DateTime());

$result = [
    'days' => $interval->days,
    'hours' => $interval -> days * 60 + $interval->h,
    'minutes' => $interval -> days * 60 + $interval->h * 24 + $interval->m
];
```